# Laravel 4: moving files once uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im having problems trying to upload photos and any kind of file on my app, because the do upload but as .tmp files and they dont display properly on my view

1.-My form,Im trying to upload a member with name, group, email, description and a photo

```
  {{Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@addMember','files'=>true)) }}
  {{ Form::label('file','Agregar Imagen',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
  {{ Form::file('file','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
  <br/>
  {{Form::text('name','',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=> 'Nombre'))}}
  {{Form::text('group','',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=> 'Cargo'))}}
  {{Form::text('email','',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=> 'Correo'))}}  
  {{Form::textarea('description','',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>''))}}
  <!-- submit buttons -->
  {{ Form::submit('Guardar') }}          
  <!-- reset buttons -->
  {{ Form::reset('Reset') }}          
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

2.-My upload function in the controller

```
public function addMember()
{
    $name = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $newname = Input::file('file')->getFilename();    
    Input::file('file')->move(storage_path(),$name);
    $subpath = storage_path();
    $path = $subpath.'/'.$newname2;
    $name2 = Input::get('name');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $description = Input::get('description');
    $group = Input::get('group');

    DB::table('contactgroups')->insert(
        array('group' => $group, 'name' => $name2, 'path' => $path, 'email' => $email, 'description' => $description)
    );
    $members = DB::table('contactgroups')->get();
    return View::make('admin.members',['members' => $members]);
}
```

I know i should be using a Model to upload things on my database but that's not the problem right now

3.- My display view

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
    @foreach($members as $member)   
        <div class = "row fondue">
                <h3><div class="col-md-12"><b><?=$member->name ?></b></div></h3>    
                <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="<?=$member->path ?>" alt="Image" class = "contact-img"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><?=$member->description ?></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><?=$member->email ?></div>

        </div>  

    @endforeach

@stop
```

and that's all...the info is saved in the database but the images are not showing properly on the view and, the files are uploaded as tmp files i dont know why

Comment: The `storage` directory is not (or should not be) publicly accessible. You will have to store the image somewhere in `public`

Comment: but i have some private documents i dont want to be public

Comment: You mean only logged in users should be able to access it?

Comment: not exactly, some documents are for public access and some documents should be only visible for admins

Comment: Okay this is possible but I would prefer it if you would delete this questions and ask a new one along the lines of "How can I use (protected) assets from the `storage` directory". In the question you would also specify how the user is verified (do you already have a route filter for that?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Laravel documentation

Moving An Uploaded File

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath);

Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files